# List index out of range (Fractional Knapsack)

Tags: python, greedy

I'm attempting to implement a greedy algorithm for the fractional knapsack problem for a coursera assignment. The course insists on not giving the inputs that cause the problem. Below is my code of the solution and the code I used for stress testing.

```
def optimal_value(capacity, weights, values):
    value = 0.

    while capacity > 0 and len(values) > 0:
        maxval = 0

        # I need values per weight
        prices = [val / wei for val, wei in zip(values, weights)]

        for i in range(len(prices)):
            if prices[i] > maxval:
                maxval = prices[i]
                best_item = i

        # put as much of the best item into the pack as we can and update the value
        added = min(capacity, weights[best_item])
        value += (added / weights[best_item]) * values[best_item]
        capacity += -added

        #print(f"prices are {prices}, values are {values}, best item is {best_item}")
        #print(f"value is {value}, added is {added}, capacity is {capacity}")

        if added == weights[best_item]:
            # we used up the best option
            values = [val for i, val in enumerate(values) if i != best_item]
            weights = [weight for i, weight in enumerate(
                weights) if i != best_item]

    return value
```

```
import numpy as np

def create_knapsack_test_case():
    capacity = np.random.randint(0, 2e6)
    n = np.random.randint(1, 1000)
    weights = np.random.randint(1, 2e6, n)
    values = np.random.randint(0, 2e6, n)

    return capacity, weights, values

for i in range(20000):
    try:
        inputs = create_knapsack_test_case()
        opt = optimal_value(*inputs)
    except:
        print(f"faulty inputs are {inputs}")
```

I'm missing an edge case and have no idea what it could be. Please help.

Comment: While your test method tests a number of random starting conditions, it is not the way to test for edge case conditions.  You need to create a small test set with probably no more than 4 entries, which allows you to tests different conditions with regard to weights, values, & goals.  For example on a recent test of pure 0-1 knapsack I used the following set of edge cases: ```'VAL': [5, 1, 3, 3],  'WT': [4, 2, 1, 3],'        'CAP': 7``` and then tried a specific series of combinations involving changing the weights, followed by changing the vals, until I found the case that failed

Comment: That seems like the way to go. I'll try it. Thank you.